# How to set ActionLink as an image

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a little question. How to set ActionLink as an image for something like this:

```
 <%= Html.ActionLink("English", "ChangeCulture", "Account",
 new {lang = "en", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl }, null)%>
```

For other ActionLink i did something like this:

```
 Html.ActionLink(" ", "About", "Home", new
 {style = "background: url('../../Content/images/img03.jpg')no-repeat center
 right;display:block; height:24px; width:24px;"})
```

But for this example it doesn't work. I want to add localization to my site in the form of images of flags. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why it wouldn't work for this link?

Comment: I've tried a lot of different ways but honestly I have no idea how to do this. Of course regarding the first ActionLink. The second one is working properly.

Comment: I wonder how can the second ActionLink that you have shown to work as you have completely messed up its arguments. You are not using the correct overload. You have mixed up route values and html attributes.

Comment: Maybe, but it works for me. Easy to check. But it isn't a question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues here...

Firstly, you are setting the routeValues paramater of ActionLink with your Html style. Add a null object between them:

```
Html.ActionLink(" ", "About", "Home", null, new
 {style = "background: url('../../Content/images/img03.jpg')no-repeat center
 right;display:block; height:24px; width:24px;"})
```

Secondly, you will want to check the url of the image is correct as you are using a relative path. Try using Url.Content to get the correct path instead.

Thirdly, the lack of a space between the url and the no-repeat flag might be affecting your browser output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Perhaps I have written unintelligibly. I want to set the first ActionLink as an image. The second one is working properly.

Comment: Sorry, but I'll need you to rewrite the question then please. I don't understand what it is you want help with.

Comment: Thank you for your interest but I have found a solution. I need to use
  new {@ class = "EnglishFlag" instead of a null object.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using html helper

tho i would recomend using TagBuilder for this.

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Create image representation of boolean in form of
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="html">The HTML.</param>
  /// <param name="boolValue">if set to <c>true</c> [bool value].</param>
  /// <param name="path">The path.</param>
  /// <param name="alt">The alt.</param>
  /// <returns>
  /// html img tag
  /// </returns>
public static string ImageForBool(this HtmlHelper html, bool boolValue, string path,ImageAlt alt)
{
  string trueVal = "tick";
  string falseVal = "x";
  string img = "<img src=\"{0}\" {1}/>";
  string altTag = string.Empty;
  path += "Content/Actions/";
  if (boolValue)
  {
    altTag = (alt == null) ? "" : "alt=\"" + alt.trueOption + "\"";
    return string.Format(img, Path.Combine(path, trueVal) + ".png", altTag);
  }
  else
  {
    altTag = (alt == null) ? "" : "alt=\"" + alt.falseOption + "\"";
    return string.Format(img, Path.Combine(path, falseVal) + ".png", altTag);
  }
}
```

this option is possibly the best for you

Alternative way

use html action link and use string.replace
using your code:

```
string tag = Html.ActionLink("[toReplaceWithImage]", "ChangeCulture", "Account",
 new {lang = "en", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl }, null).ToString()

tag.Replace("[toReplaceWithImage]", "<img src=\"path\">");
```